# How to execute a very heavy process exposed as REST services from wildfly?

Tags: java, rest, jboss, wildfly

I have a process that processes an input file, uses 100% of the processor (uses 16 cores), and 8 GB of RAM. I currently run it directly from the console. But I need to call this process from a REST service. The service must be asynchronous, and there will be another service to consult the output of the first service called. The input files must be queued, because it can only be processed one at a time.

I use RestEasy on Wildfly.

My query is:

What architecture do you suggest to call this process?

I have these possible solutions.

- Call from my EJB to JAR with Runtime. And have a queue of files in a database.
- Transform my JAR into a Demon, which is constantly monitoring a directory. And they will be storing the files there. And that the demon took one by one the files according to the date of arrival.
- Copy the classes in my EAR project, and call them as a simple EJB, and let wildfly manage the resources. This would also imply having a file queue in a database.

Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Have the REST service submit a task to a singleThreadExecutor. Execute the big process in that task.

Comment: Go cloud - have the REST service put the work into a queue of some sort and have a pool of workers take it off of the queue and work on it.  Store files in a cloud store (i.e. S3 in the Amazon world).  Place status messages into a data store of some sort (file, DB, etc).  And if you had a bunch of machines would it have to be processed in order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing a queue use a JMS implementation or Kafka. Cloud solutions exist from Google and AWS. Have your REST endpoint publish to the queue and your "daemon" receive from it.

From there it's easy to pull these apart into microservice architecture

Answer (score 0):

Technically the solution is simple: have a rest endpoint call another Stateless EJB with `@Asynchronous` annotation. If you want to track the status, use some kind of Job entity, that you create (synchronously) when you receive the request, then start the async job with this Job entity as param and update it from your async task.
There is however a more conceptual problem: why do you need to invoke such long running op on your web server? With requirement like this it is going to be very difficult to scale your app, handle failover(what happens if your server crashes during processing)..

If you need to do IO or computation heavy task like this in java env, have a look at [batch processing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/batch-1965499.html) - jberet or spring batch will do the job. That way you can process your file in chunks, paralelize the compution and spread the load more evenly.  If you are doing some video processing or similiar task, consider using a dedicated machines with some kind of job queue(celery, kafka...) for that, and just let your server handle the rest layer and job monitoring.

Comment: The number of users is very limited. A maximum of 10 to 20 clients, and each client can only have one request in the queue. I'm building a scheduling engine as a service. The client will send the conditions of the problem, the server runs a genetic algorithm (it is the process that consumes many resources) and solves the problem. In case there is another process running, the request must be queued.

Comment: Do not spend time on inventing your own scheduling and queueing. You have all you need in jee server. Create a jms queue, register a jms listener on it(if you want to process messages sequentially) or create an MDB(if you want parallel exec), Have a rest endpoint create the job entity, submit it to the queue and return a handle to user e.g. job id, which he can use to track the progress of the calculation. You can find examples for jms handling at [javaee-samples](javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/tree/master/jms) or [wildfly-samples](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart)

Comment: If @asynchronous method is used, how the transactions are handled? Will it start new transaction like started for calling slsb from MDB?

Comment: Yes, it will start a new transaction, similar to message driven bean or onTime for scheduled jobs.